# Use string as variable name in Angular 2+ and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In regular JavaScript we can add a property to `window` global object with name from string, like this:

```js
const str = "myVar";
window[str] = "Value";
console.log(myVar);
```

But is there a way to do the similar job in Angular 2/4 and Typescript? We can store regular variables in component using `this.myVar`, but is there a way to create the same variable using string for the variable name? Something like:

```
const str = "myVar";
this[str] = "Value";
// the result should be the similar as this.myVar = "Value";
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So did you try this and fail?

Comment: @echonax, yes, I did: TSLint gives me an error

Comment: Technically, this doesn't "create a variable" but add a property to the `window` object.

Comment: @Henry, yes, my explanation is not absolutely right, sorry

Comment: Henry is right, this will work but typescript will give the error in typechecking. I don't think there's a way to make it work like this.

Comment: @echonax, no, it doesn't work at all: I don't see my `console.log`

Comment: @CommercialSuicide https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aszgmk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @echonax, it's a little strange, because I can't just compile the project after adding this rows. I have updated the answer with compile error...

Comment: @CommercialSuicide ah yes, it will not compile because of typescript check but it is a legit code actually (that's what I tried to point out).

Comment: @echonax, thanks, it's a good point to notice, but Ideally I'd like to find a way to use it without compile errors. But thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can allow dynamic properties on your class:

```
class Test {
  [key: string]: any;

  constructor() {
    const str = "myVar";
    this[str] = "Value";
    console.log(this.myVar);
  }
}
```

But make sure you really need it because you're loosing typechecking with it:

```
class Test {

  [key: string]: any;

  constructor() {
    this.teet(); // typo and therefore you will get an error in runtime
  }

  test() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you can access using the following & Typescript accepts this syntax

```
this["myVar"]
```

instead of

`this.myVar`

Comment: It's a little unexpected behavior for me, but yes, it works! And without compile errors! So are `this["myVar"] ` and `this.myVar` different? In my understanding for now they should be the same...

Comment: @CommercialSuicide i don't think this answers the question, this is just using `this[str]` in another manner. You should check yurzui's answer.

Comment: @echonax, right! yurzui 's answer is better than mine ;)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide also dynamic addition of properties should be avoided as it defeats the purpose of Typescript

Comment: @Thabung, just one time, when I will need to use object properties as variable names ;)

Comment: I must say "Avoid it". It's TypeScript